# How repeat fade and animate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate, fadein

I run this code and it works, but when $(".box3").click, $(".box1") does not fade in and animate, it is directly shown in the window. After other $(".box2") and $(".box3") have some problems in the second time.

Could it be that fadeIn and animate only run one time? I it want to run more times but still have the fadeIn, fadeOut and animate effect.

thanks for answer .

```js
$(function() {
  $(".box2,.box3").hide();

  $(".box1").click(function() {
    $(".box1").animate({
      left: "1200px"
    }, 1000).fadeOut();
    $(".box2").fadeIn();
  });

  $(".box2").click(function() {
    $(".box2").animate({
      left: "1200px"
    }, 1000).fadeOut();
    $(".box3").fadeIn();
  });

  $(".box3").click(function() {
    $(".box3").animate({
      left: "1200px"
    }, 1000).fadeOut();
    $(".box1").fadeIn();
  });
})
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

.box1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 500px;
}

.box2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(2, 149, 246);
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 500px;
}

.box3 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(22, 187, 0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
<div class="box3"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation :** As all the elements had similar kind of event bind, I made a `commonEvent` function, which reduces code. The `fadeOut` function accepts a callback function as an argument, which gets executed, when the `fadeOut` gets executed. When `.box1` is clicked, it's `left` property is set to `1200px`. That is why, I changed it's value back to `500px`, i.e. initial value, in it's callback function.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".box2,.box3").hide();

  $(".box1").click(function() {
    commonEvent($(this), $(".box2"));
  });

  $(".box2").click(function() {
    commonEvent($(this), $(".box3"));
  });

  $(".box3").click(function() {
    commonEvent($(this), $(".box1"));
  });
})

function commonEvent(element, other) {
  element.animate({
    left: "1200px"
  }, 1000).fadeOut("normal", () => {
    element.css("left", "500px");
  })
  other.fadeIn();
}
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

.box1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 500px;
}

.box2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(2, 149, 246);
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 500px;
}

.box3 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(22, 187, 0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
<div class="box3"></div>
```

Comment: thanks you answer for me . help a lot ,besacue i am noob code

Comment: Glad to help. Keep learning. And don't forget to upvote and mark the answer correct. Happy coding :)